# how to perform oauth2.0 token request in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

i'm trying to request oauth token in php usign cURL but the response is always  {"error":"invalid_request"}

my code:

```
 $client_id = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
 $client_secret = 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET';
 $url = my url '/identityiq/oauth2/token';

 
 
$requestData = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret
];

   
$ch = curl_init();

$headers['Content-Type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

i tryed with postman autorization and it's working

Comment: Could be of many reasons: are you in SSL? cacert installed? is "my url" as true variable ($my_url)? I would suggest you to look the Jumbojett OIDC library https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP

Comment: If you made it work in Postman, you can use Postman to autogenerate equivalent php code for you. See if that helps

Comment: why this `CURLOPT_POST` is set to `false` ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the `client_id` and `client_secret` needed to be included in the call's header and encoded into base64.

```
$headers['Authorization'] = "Basic " . base64_encode('CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET');
```